# How to find N last non-empty cells of a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to find last 3 filled cells in a row for a data frame.

| Unique ID | Fruit1 | Fruit2 | Fruit3 | Fruit4 | Fruit5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Apple | Banana | Fig | Melon |  |
| 1235 | Orange | Grape |  |  |  |
| 1236 | Plum | Orange | Pear | Papaya | Apricot |
| 1237 | Guava |  |  |  |  |
| 1238 | Kiwi | Cherry | Peach |  |  |

Final result should look like

| Unique ID | Fruit1 | Fruit2 | Fruit3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Banana | Fig | Melon |
| 1235 | Orange | Grape |  |
| 1236 | Pear | Papaya | Apricot |
| 1237 | Guava |  |  |
| 1238 | Kiwi | Cherry | Peach |

Moreover, what if i wanted to filter for fruits containing %G% or %P%
My result would then need to look like:

| Unique ID | Fruit1 | Fruit2 | Fruit3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1235 | Grape |  |  |
| 1236 | Pear | Papaya |  |
| 1237 | Guava |  |  |
| 1238 | Peach |  |  |

Comment: Where did this data come from?  pandas is really better suited to column-oriented operation than row-oriented.  It might be easier to do this processing before you convert to a dataframe.

Comment: Data from an excel sheet. Yes, hence my iloc and other operations not giving me expected results, how do you suggest I handle it before? (FYR, Actual dataset is too big to transpose and then select last 3 non empty rows. Would end up with 10k columns xD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Fruit1': {1234: 'Apple', 1235: 'Orange', 1236: 'Plum', 1237: 'Guava', 1238: 'Kiwi'},
 'Fruit2': {1234: 'Banana', 1235: 'Grape', 1236: 'Orange', 1237: np.nan, 1238: 'Cherry'},
 'Fruit3': {1234: 'Fig', 1235: np.nan, 1236: 'Pear', 1237: np.nan, 1238: 'Peach'},
 'Fruit4': {1234: 'Melon', 1235: np.nan, 1236: 'Papaya', 1237: np.nan, 1238: np.nan},
 'Fruit5': {1234: np.nan, 1235: np.nan, 1236: 'Apricot', 1237: np.nan, 1238: np.nan}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
        Fruit1  Fruit2  Fruit3  Fruit4  Fruit5
1234    Apple   Banana  Fig     Melon   NaN
1235    Orange  Grape   NaN     NaN     NaN
1236    Plum    Orange  Pear    Papaya  Apricot
1237    Guava   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1238    Kiwi    Cherry  Peach   NaN     NaN
```

---

**Code**

```
(df
 .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[x.notna()][-3:].tolist()), axis=1)
 .rename(columns=lambda x: 'Fruit{}'.format(x + 1)))
```

output:

```
       Fruit1   Fruit2  Fruit3
1234    Banana  Fig     Melon
1235    Orange  Grape   NaN
1236    Pear    Papaya  Apricot
1237    Guava   NaN     NaN
1238    Kiwi    Cherry  Peach
```

The second problem is possible with similar code by replacing value that does not start with G or P with NaN.

Comment: Could you give me the filter condition as well replacing value that does not start with G or P with NaN.

substring = 'G|P'
df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains(substring, case=False).any(), axis=1)]

Was trying something like this but unable to add '= np.nan' to replace it.

Any other simpler solution would help too

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
(df.set_index('Unique ID')
 .stack()
 .groupby(level=0).tail(3)
 .to_frame()
 .assign(cc = lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).set_index('cc',append=True)
 .droplevel(1)[0]
 .unstack())
```

Output:

```
cc              0       1        2
Unique ID                         
1234       Banana     Fig    Melon
1235       Orange   Grape      NaN
1236         Pear  Papaya  Apricot
1237        Guava     NaN      NaN
1238         Kiwi  Cherry    Peach
```